# Can I set my wireless network card to connect only to 2.4 GHz wireless networks?

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, network-adapter

On a laptop or 2-in-1 device with Windows 10 (like the Surface Pro), is there a way to set the WiFi network card to detect and connect only to wireless networks on the 2.4 GHz frequency?
My devices work also with 5 GHz networks and I'm interested (for some experiments) to have them connect to WiFi only on the 2.4 GHz wireless frequency. 
Is this possible? How can you make your network card ignore 5 GHz wireless networks, detect and connect only to 2.4 GHz wireless networks?

Comment: Check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/774256/how-do-i-use-my-dual-band-wi-fi-card-to-connect-to-5ghz-and-2-4ghz-simultaneousl).

Comment: Check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/520060/how-to-select-wifi-channel-with-windows-7-adhoc) also.

Comment: Does the "Advanced" section in your WiFi adapter's properties page show anything to set the IEEE mode or allowed frequencies?What's the name of your WiFi card?

Comment: @vembutech Your suggestions have nothing to do with my question.

Comment: @nullterminatedstring I need to do this on multiple Windows devices. One of them is a Surface Pro 3 with a Marvell AVASTAR Wireless-AC Network Controller. I need a solution that works for almost any kind of dual-band network card.

Comment: @CorporateGeek Shouldn't Windows create one network profile for each frequency?Open a admin command line and execute `netsh wlan show profiles`, does it show multiple profiles for one SSID?

Comment: @CorporateGeek Sorry the method I mentioned is not working, you need to directly look in the registry instead.Open "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\" in regedit and check if there are 2 different profiles (registry subkeys) with your network's name as value for "Description".

Comment: @CorporateGeek Without installing additional software and without using the driver specific settings in the wifi adapter's settings you won't exactly achieve what you want, especially the thing with detecting only 2.4 GHz networks is difficult.

Comment: @nullterminatedstring Do you know some useful third-party software for this job?

Comment: @nullterminatedstring What you say about profiles doesn't help. I have to work with a mesh WiFi network that broadcasts on the same network name both the 5 GHz and the 2.4 GHz frequency. I need to find a way so that some devices detect and connect only on the 2.4 GHz frequency.